# TDD and 3 Tier Architecture

Tags: tdd

I need to implement TDD in a 3 Tier Architecture.

The examples in books and blogs makes sense ,when testing the occurrences of a charater in a string or testing the Stack's Pop function.But when it comes to N-Tier Application,where we have UI,Business Tier and Data Tier and the Data Tier in turns calls the required Stored Procedures and gets the data.

The concept behind TDD is to perform tests in isolation,which means that we have to Mock or Fake the Data.

But my doubts about this methodology is that what should the TDD test.
What I have understood is that ,it tests whether for example the GetCustomer function returns the expected result.

Now my question is what if the Stored Procedure has a Bug,the TDD wont catch that Bug as the Data is not extracted using the Buggy Stored Procedure.
Also how to test a Business & Data Tier function which calls a Stored Procedure and the Stored Procedure has all the Business Rules implemented.

And also how to implement TDD for CRUD operations?

Any examples will be very helpful to fully understand the concept of TDD

Regards

Comment: TDD is not the only form of testing.  It's just one of many.  Were you told by someone that other testing (integration testing, performance testing, etc.) were no longer to be used?  Where did you get the idea that TDD was the only kind of testing you would do?

Comment: When you say you need to use TDD, do you mean you want to do it, or someone else wants you to do it? Just curious.

Comment: It also sounds to me that you may be confusing TDD with unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Tests are written to prove that the functional and business requirements are met. Therefore, I code against the public interfaces of the classes in use. The public interfaces drill down to the internal and private classes. If an exception is thrown at a lower level, or if the function returns the wrong data, I capture it in the test against the business rule.

For example, if Employee is a business class and it invokes EmployeeSerializer.GetAll(), I only need to test Employee.GetAll. If EmployeeSerializer() doesn't return the right data, I'll know it. If EmployeeSerializer throws an unexpected exception, I'll know it. If EmployeeSerializer doesn't throw the correct exceptions, I'll know it.

Don't code your tests to validate implementation details. Code them to test business rules. That means you test the business objects. To facilitate this effort, I mark my data access objetcts INTERNAL, so I can't test them outside of the business context in which they're intended to be used.

But that's me, and I'm sure others have differing opinions.

ADDENDUM: Keep business rules out of stored procedures as much as possible. Also, set up known tests using [Setup] and [TearDown]. Remember that a test tests an entire business rule. You are free to do as much work as possible to set up the test, so long as the test executes in isolation and you can restore the environment to its original state when the test completes. So if you want to insert data, make sure you have a business class method that does that. The same for updating, deleting, and selecting.

Comment: +1: "Keep business rules out of stored procedures as much as possible"

Answer (score 1):

First of I'd say read a bit more about Mocks (You mock roles... not data / objects).

W.r.t. to your example, I'd have

1. Unit tests against the presentation class/viewmodel (your UI tier). Here I'd mock the business layer/role.. e.g. verify that the presentation classes call the right methods on the services when I do X
2. Unit tests against the domain classes (Business tier). Here I mock the Data Access layer.. e.g. verify that GetCustomer() is called when I do X
3. Integration tests that test that MyRepository.GetCustomer() actually fetches data out of a "real" test DB correctly. So ideally the bug in your StoredProc should be caught and flagged here.

In addition to this, there might be bugs where the two parties on either side of a contract have a different idea of how the other person should behave. For that you'd write some end-to-end acceptance tests that exercise all the components wired together (like they would be in production).

TDD can be used for all of the above.